# Flutter Plugin Project with .AAR

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, aar

I have a private library that is compiled in .AAR, I have made a plugin for flutter from the library, so I can use it in Flutter. The thing is that I have not been able so far to make it work implementing the library in my main app.

I have two libraries, let's call them a and a2.
The a is a .jar and works great, the a2 is .aar.

I have made a separate module and has this:

File ipc = file("a2.aar")

configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file(ipc))

From there in the build.gradle:

implementation project(':a2')

and in the settings.gradle:

include ':app', ':a2'.

Now wanting to implement it in the normal project:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/user/dev/file/android/build.gradle' line: 80
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':a'.

> Project with path ':a2' could not be found in project ':a'.

If I implement in the settings.gradle:

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':a:compileDebugAidl'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':a:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :a2.
> Required by:
> project :a
> No matching configuration of project :a2 was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:app' with value 'dev', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

I have tried different things and have not been able to get anything to work, such as trying to make it not a module. But the only way I have found that will work is to create an .aar module.